# How to write this regex to export links

Tags: c#, regex

Here the example.

Starts with : `imgurl=`
Ends with : `&amp`

Example extraction

```
asfasfasfasimgurl=http://www.mysite.com&ampasgasgas
```

Result: `http://www.mysite.com`

So how can I write regex to extract all instances like this?

Comment: What have you tried? What if there are multiple occurrences of `imgurl=` or `$amp`? From first to last, from first to first, from last to first, from last to last? Provide some more examples and your own attempt, please.

Comment: @m.buettner thanks for answer. instead of thinking too much pattern for this particular example may work for me. I am also trying myself right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind and lookahead

```
 (?<=imgurl=).*?(?=&amp)
```

- [Lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Greedy Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201398/greedy-quantifiers)

You can get a list of urls using

```
 List<String> urls=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(x=>x.Value)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks a lot working awesome can you please explain it to me i also want to learn how to right regex :D

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG then [this tutorial](http://regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is what you want to read ;)

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex could be:

```
(?:imgurl=)(.*)(?:&amp)
```

the (?:[stuff here]) is a non-capture group. It requires the pattern to match, but not capture/extract. The (.*) captures everything in-between the two non-capture groups.

Also to learn more about capture groups you can read here
[What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)